# Landscape Trial Limitations

Tags: landscape, ubuntu-advantage

I am currently using the Landscape Saas trial with 30 desktops. Once the trial is over, can I purchase 30 ubuntu advantage desktop licenses and continue to use the same landscape "domain" with out having to rebuild it? Is it possible for Saas and ubuntu advantage to co-exist, meaning that one computer is changed $0.01 per hour while the other one is good for the year, but both are managed by the same landscape administration console?

Also the landscape user guide says that I can have 1000 administrators, but I am limited to 5. I am assuming this is a trial limitation and that this will go away after the trial has ended?

Comment: I would say you should ask Cannonical directly via https://landscape.canonical.com/contact-us.

Comment: I tried several times, but they never got back to me. I'm also hoping to save some else some grief by asking the question here.

Comment: @Andrew The only people who really know the Canonical systems is Canonical.  Licensing questions are, in turn, are really only answered by them.  Very few of the Ask Ubuntu community, even myself, know the Landscape and Ubuntu Advantage licensing parameters (I should point out it's very expensive to cover 30 desktops with Ubuntu Advantage, too, by the way)

Comment: I think, however, that this a good question for the Ubuntu community. If I am ever able to get a hold of Canonical, I will answer this question my self.

Comment: @Andrew the question remains - how many people *actually* use Landscape and therefore know the answer to whether SaaS and Ubuntu Advantage are handled separately (pretty 100% certain they are though).  But again, as I say in my answer, only Canonical can truly answer the question./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a hold of a canonical representative. Below is a direct quote from the representative's email.

> 1. Number of admins in Landscape - there are 5 only in the
>      self-service SaaS Landscape. Answer: If you have Ubuntu Advantage, you
>      can submit a ticket and ask support to add more admin seats- it could
>      be 20, that is not an issue. For on-premise Landscape, the default
>      number is 100, so you do not need to ask the support team to add more.
> 2. Is transfer from self-service SaaS Landscape to Ubuntu Advantage possible?  Unfortunately not- it would need to be a new account,
>      sorry.

Over the phone I was told that I could buy landscape seats at $25 per year per desktop, without support using a quote from a representative. The $25 seats are still under advantage, so I'm assuming the 50 seat minimum still applies.

I was also told that the licences are tied to the landscape account not the desktops. If you run out of landscape seats using Ubuntu advantage, it would not let you join anymore machines to the administration console, unless you buy more seats.